# webpack css-loader parse failure

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I'm using webpack loaders (css-loader/style-loader) and I just don't know why the simple css code below,

```
body {
    background: blue;
}
```

keeps resulting in this error,

```
ERROR in ./app/main.css 1:5
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> body {
    background: blue;
}
@ ./app/index.js 1:0-21
```

this is a snippet from webpack.config.js

```
const Paths = {
    app: __dirname + '/app',
    build: __dirname + '/build',
};
module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css&/,
            use: [{loader: 'style-loader'},
                  {loader: 'css-loader'}],
            include: Paths.app
        }]
    }
```

and this is my package.json snippet

```
"devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.15.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8"
  },
```

this is my first Webpack,css attempt, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You have to import your css.

add `const s = require('./main.css');`
to `index.js`

Let me know if you are still having problems with it.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. In index.js I had require('./main.css'); problem still remains